# How to get the maximum number of hosts from IP address

Tags: java, binary, byte, ip-address

My question is How to get the maximum number of hosts that can be used on the network to which the specified IP address belongs.

i have a java method like this, which has two arguments ip address and subnet mask address.
When i google i found the formula but i dont know how to write with java.
The formula is

> The maximum number of hosts can be determined from the number of hosts
>   available in the network, It is the number obtained by subtracting two
>   of less and broadcast address.

```
public static int maxHostNum(String _ip, String _subnetMask) throws UnknownHostException {
    byte[] bIP = InetAddress.getByName(_ip).getAddress();
    byte[] bSB = InetAddress.getByName(_subnetMask).getAddress();
    byte[] bNT = new byte[4];
    for (int i=0; i<bIP.length; i++) {
        bNT[i] = (byte) (~bSB[i] | bIP[i]);
    }
    String broadcastAddress = InetAddress.getByAddress(bNT).toString();

    // i dont know the rest

    return maxHostNum;
}
```

**I know Apache common library can do this but i just want to do without using library**

Comment: For example, if ip address = 192.168.2. 65, subnet mask address = 255.255.255.192, then the maximum numer of hosts = 62

Comment: Do you really need IP? I think only subnet mask is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

A subnet mask determines which part of an IP address is the network IP and which part is the device's IP by performing a bitwise AND between the mask and the IP to get the network IP. For example:

```
192.168.3.45 ->    11000000.10101000.00000011.00101101
255.255.255.240 -> 11111111.11111111.11111111.11110000
Network IP ->      11000000.10101000.00000011.00100000 <- because the last 4 digits of the subnet mask were 0 here, the resulting network IP bits are also 0.
Host IP ->         00000000.00000000.00000000.00001101
```

So since in the above example the last 4 digits determine the host IP, you should have 2^4 available IP addresses, but you actually have 2^4 - 2 because the addresses where all of the host's bits are either 1 or 0 are special and can't be used for specific devices.

So to know how many host IPs a network can support you can simply invert the subnet mask's values and turn it into an int:

```
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < bSB.length; i++) {
    result <<= 8; // Bit shift 8 digits to the left.
    result |= ~bSB[i]; // Perform bitwise or-equals with the bitwise inverted value of bSB[i]
}
result <<= 8;
result -= 2; // Special IPs
```

The resulting integer is the number of possible host IPs.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easy if you can convert to cidr notation than you will end up with 2 formulas :

Nbr subnets = 2^(cidr-class).
Nbr hosts = 2^(32-cidr) -2.

Where class =8 if class A; 16 if class B; 24 if class C.

Hope that helps.